# How to convert the Mat object to a Bitmap while perserving the color?

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, android-bitmap, opencv3.1

In the App I am developing I open the Camera using `OpenCV4Android` using `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2` and when I touch the screen I set that frame as an image inside an `ImageView` as shown below in the code.
the problem is the image set to the `imageview` is always of different color than the preview on the camera as shown in the picture. I believe that this issue has something to do with the conversion I made which is stated in the code below

My question is how to convert the Mat object to a `Bitmap` preserving the same color?

**pic**

[image]
**code**:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame");
    if (mRGBT != null) {
        mRGBT.release();
    }

    mRGBT = inputFrame.rgba().t();
    Core.flip(mRGBT, mRGBT, 1);
    Imgproc.resize(mRGBT, mRGBT, inputFrame.rgba().size());

    if (touched) {
        touched = false;
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBT, mRGBT, CvType.CV_8U);
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBT.cols(), mRGBT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRGBT, bitmap);

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    return mRGBT;
}
```

Comment: OpenCV works with BGR images. You convert the frame to RGB.

Comment: As Dan has stated the colour order is incorrect your Red and Blue channels are in a different order

Comment: @DanMašek do u mean this line: Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBT.cols(), mRGBT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);..if that is what you mean, there is no option for BGR!!

Answer (score 4):

You are converting the image incorrectly.

If you want the bitmap to be a color image, you don't need the `cvtColor`. 
`inputFrame.rgba()` returns a RGBA Mat and that is the input you need for `Utils.matToBitmap` (See [JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap-org.opencv.core.Mat-android.graphics.Bitmap-boolean-)).

```
if (touched) {
    touched = false;
    final Bitmap bitmap = 
            Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBT.cols(), mRGBT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRGBT, bitmap);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want the bitmap to be a gray image use `Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY`:

```
if (touched) {
    touched = false;
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBT, mRGBT, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
    final Bitmap bitmap = 
            Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBT.cols(), mRGBT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRGBT, bitmap);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

If you need to work with bitmaps `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` add `true` as a third parameter in `Utils.matToBitmap`, so the Mat is converted to alpha premultiplied format (See [JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap-org.opencv.core.Mat-android.graphics.Bitmap-boolean-)).

```
final Bitmap bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBT.cols(), mRGBT.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mRGBT, bitmap, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it works fine:

```
Mat mat = inputFrame.rgba();
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bm);
```

Comment: actually i have the same problem when i use Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888

Comment: @user2121 Try to remove the previous code step by step and find out what's the problem

Comment: what should i do to reverse this i mean bitmap to inputframes