# Frame and keras model

Tags: python, android, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a model which predicting the steering angle of a car from a picture which I like to implement in a android project by getting the frames from the camera.

in my Python code I'm using a h5 file instead of the tflite file in which the picture is converted to numpy and get processed using Cv2 lib.

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import cv2


def img_preprocess(img):
    img = img[60:135,:,:]
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,  (3, 3), 0)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (200, 66))
    img = img/255
    return img


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    image1 = Image.open("Gta2.png")

    image1 = np.asarray(image1)
    image1 = img_preprocess(image1)
    image1 = np.array([image1])
    steering_angle = float(model.predict(image1))
    if(steering_angle > 0):
        print('turn right')
        print('turn wheel : {}'.format(steering_angle))

    else:
        print('turn left')
        print('turn wheel : {}'.format(steering_angle))
```

I've been imported the model.tflite to my project assets and know I need to process the CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame object from the camera to fit to my model input.

the model input and output.

[image]

so my questions are:

1. How process the CvCameraViewFrame Object as in the python code in the 'img_preprocess' function?
2. How to reach the input specs?

my android code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your `Mat frame` to Bitmap, such as the [solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957955/how-to-convert-the-mat-object-to-a-bitmap-while-perserving-the-color).

And then use TFLite Task library [ImageClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/image_classifier) to run the inference. Here is an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ff4ddd4609f76d8b7d085033a9b4cd9a3c6d26bd/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L194-L218) of how to use ImageClassifier, which comes from the [TFLite Image Classification reference app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android).

Alternatively, you can write your own code to process the image and run inference using Interpreter. See the example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ff4ddd4609f76d8b7d085033a9b4cd9a3c6d26bd/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_support/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L250-L267).